# Sending your application to background when back button is pressed in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Flutter code to send the app to background when back button is pressed. I want to minimize the app to background when i click the back button like home button does to apps and now when i click the back button it kills the app. I am using willPopScope to get it work but no help

Comment: I believe you can't do it in Flutter as of now. You can try `MethodChannel` and do it natively both sides. Do you want me to put a solution for Android?

Answer (score 13):

I found this package on pub.dev and it worked well for me and it's easy to use

https://pub.dev/packages/move_to_background

Comment: This approach have worked pretty well for me!

Comment: didn't work for me today with two warnings: """MoveToBackgroundPlugin.java:13: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;
MoveToBackgroundPlugin.java:24: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
  public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {"""

Comment: Sorry for downvoted, but this lib is no longer maintained, please avoid using it and warning incoming users don't use it!

Answer (score 5):

**03.2020 UPDATE**

As @user1717750 wrote - The dart code remains the same, so it's:

```
var _androidAppRetain = MethodChannel("android_app_retain");

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
        return Future.value(true);
      } else {
        _androidAppRetain.invokeMethod("sendToBackground");
        return Future.value(false);
      }
    } else {
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    ...
  ),
);
}
```

The code in the MainActivity() should look like this:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "android_app_retain").apply {
        setMethodCallHandler { method, result ->
            if (method.method == "sendToBackground") {
                moveTaskToBack(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is this methode work for android and ios ? or just for Android

Comment: @ingmbk for Android, on iOS you don't have system back pressing, so you don't need such a method

Comment: Sorry for downvoted, but with import just copy part of the code isn't useful at all.

Answer (score 2):

**07.2023 UPDATE**

Following @Muscler answer:

Platform code (Kotlin) changed again:

```
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull
    import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
    import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
    import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

    class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
        override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
            super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

            MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "android_app_retain").apply {
                setMethodCallHandler { method, result ->
                    if (method.method == "sendToBackground") {
                        moveTaskToBack(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

If it changes again, you should look at flutter docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab

The dart code still the same, so it's:

```
var _androidAppRetain = MethodChannel("android_app_retain");

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
        return Future.value(true);
      } else {
        _androidAppRetain.invokeMethod("sendToBackground");
        return Future.value(false);
      }
    } else {
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    ...
  ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From here:
https://medium.com/stuart-engineering/%EF%B8%8F-the-tricky-task-of-keeping-flutter-running-on-android-2d51bbc60882

PLAT FORM CODE:

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

        MethodChannel(flutterView, "android_app_retain").apply {
            setMethodCallHandler { method, result ->
                if (method.method == "sendToBackground") {
                    moveTaskToBack(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

YOUR DART CODE:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          if (Navigator.of(context).canPop()) {
            return Future.value(true);
          } else {
            _androidAppRetain.invokeMethod("sendToBackground");
            return Future.value(false);
          }
        } else {
          return Future.value(true);
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: MainDrawer(),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

CREDIT TO:
Sergi Castellsagué Millán

Comment: Sorry for downvoted, but with import just copy part of the code isn't useful at all.

Comment: No worries.  Flutter is something breaks itself for every release.  I quitted Flutter.